# Issue with a '?' character

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on an ASP.NET with C# app on WebForms.
I have textbox which I am using to send SMS to mobile phones using an API.

Whenever I put a ? in the textbox it disables all the events on the page, no event gets fired.

Not able to understand what is an issue?

Comment: depends upon your API. you will have to paste code

Comment: <asp:Button ID="butsend" runat="server" Text="Send" onclick="butsend_Click" OnClientClick="return validatesms()"/>

Above is the HTML code of the button.

Comment: I think the problem lies in `validatesms`.

Comment: Do you passing textbox text as query string parameter to API you mentioned?

Comment: @I4V I have tried after removing this validatesms, does not work.

Comment: @YuriyRozhovetskiy yes, I am passing the text as querystring parameter but I am using HttpWebRequest to call the api, this ? mark makes all other button events disabled

Comment: @Chatur show your code

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="tbmessage" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" ForeColor="#808080"
                                 onkeydown="countlen()" onkeyup="countlen()" Width="400px" CssClass="inputDsgn"></asp:TextBox>

Above is my textbox.

Bellow is the JS function its calling:

`code`
function countlen() {
           var num = parseInt(document.getElementById("<%=tbmessage.ClientID%>").value.length);
           document.getElementById("<%=tbmscount.ClientID %>").value = Math.ceil(num / 160);
           document.getElementById("<%=tbcount.ClientID %>").value = num;
       }
`code`

Comment: And actually its not because of ? but a combination of <?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, because it is a special regex character?
Hard to answer without any code, but try to escape the question mark

> \?